# Markov Chains and transition semigoups

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

I'm trying to figure out what the following statement refers to.

A process $X$ is markov with transitions semigroup $(K_t)_{t\geq0}$ and initial distribution $\mu$ if and only if for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, for any $0=t_0<...<t_n$ and for all measurable functions $f_0,...,f_n:S\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ we have

$\mathbb{E}[f_0(X_{t_0})\cdots f_n(X_{t_n})]=\int_S{\mu(dx_0)f_0(x_0)}\cdots\int_S{K_{t_n-t_{n-1}}(x_{n-1},dx_n)f_n(x_n)}$

What is suggesting this Statement? Why it consider expectation instead to conditional expectation, and making use of the transition semigroup? I have some trouble with the integrals too. Is it to consider as a disjoint product of integrals?

Thanks for any suggestion :)

Comment: This gives the distribution $\mu_{t_0,\ldots,t_n}$ of every finite family $(X_{t_0},\ldots,X_{t_n})$ by specifying the integral of every function $f_0\otimes\cdots\otimes f_n$ (correcting a misprint of yours) with respect to this measure. More generally, for every (say) measurable nonnegative function $g$, one asks that $$\mu_{t_0,\ldots,t_n}(g)=E(g(X_{t_0},\ldots,X_{t_n}))$$ is $$\mu_{t_0,\ldots,t_n}(g)=\int\cdots\iint_{S^{n+1}}f(x_0,\ldots,x_n)\mu(dx_0)K_{t_1-t_0}(x_0,dx_1)\ldots K_{t_n-t_{n-1}}(x_{n-1},dx_n).$$

Comment: This could be abbreviated as $$\mu_{t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_n}(dx_0dx_1\ldots dx_n)=\mu(dx_0)K_{t_1-t_0}(x_0,dx_1)\ldots K_{t_n-t_{n-1}}(x_{n-1},dx_n).$$

Comment: @Did you maybe mean $g(x_0,...,x_n)$ in the integral above? is it then just another way to write $g$ as $g(X_{t_0},...,X_{t_n})=(f_0(X_0),...,f_n(X_n))$ right?

Comment: Yes $f$ in the RHS should be $g$. No this is not just another way to write $g$, the case $(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto g(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ being strictly more general than the case $(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto f_0(x_0)\times f_1(x_1)\times\cdots\times f(x_n)$.

Comment: I don't get it then. What you wrote I know. But if I want to clarify the distribution of the vector, why is he using a special case of this statement? What is convenient and why should this give the same conclusion as your more general case?

Comment: The special case is enough to determine the joint law. The general case is almost the naked definition. What is the mystery?

Comment: Ok. Wrote in this way it makes more sense :) thanks a lot

Comment: ?? "This way" simply rewrites what was already on the page. You are welcome.